# Docker RabbitMQ Spring java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitmq: Name or service not known

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq

i m trying to deploy a Spring Server on Docker. The Spring server is connecting to a RabbitMQ Server that runs in another app. I get an error while connecting to the rabbitmq. I added the host in my application.properties, didnt work. Than added to the app-container as environment variable and still doesnt work. I also rebuilded the jar and changed the images version.

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672" #JMS Port
      - "15672:15672" #Management Port - default user:pass = guest:guest

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "hospital"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - mysql_bridge
    restart: always

  springboot-docker-compose-app-container:
    image: app-image
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/hospital?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - db
    volumes:
      - /data/VerzorgerSOAP
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - mysql_bridge
      - rabbiy_mq

networks:
  mysql_bridge:
  rabbiy_mq:
```

Also this is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://db:3306/hospital?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false

server.ssl.enabled=false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.rabbitmq.host= rabbitmq
```

This is the error i get

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitmq
```

Comment: RabbitMQ is not connected to rabbiy_mq. Just add networks to the configuration of RabbitMQ

Comment: You could also delete all of the `networks:` in the file and let everything be on the automatically-created `default` network.

Comment: Thank you very much, i edited and works, but know i get `org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: @Siespi123 did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you all.

Comment: @Siespi123 please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The networks configuration was missing for rabbitmq in the dockercompose file:

```
rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672" #JMS Port
      - "15672:15672" #Management Port - default user:pass = guest:guest
    networks:
      - rabbiy_mq
```

Another solution suggested by @david-maze is to remove all `networks`